# Specify port inside the mail() function

Tags: php, smtp

[I haven't found a coherent answer to my quesion here :(](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

My server's ISP has blocked the default SMTP port, so I need to switch it manually from 25 to 587.

```
mail("example@example.com","Hello","World"); //This uses the default value
```

PS.
I don't know why the answer had been removed - [that link](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm) was very useful... however, I suppose it could be accomplished in simplier way.

Comment: If you're using windows http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp-port

Comment: If you are onder windows, see `Mike B`'s answer. If you are under linux, it would normally use your normal MTA, so configure that one. If all else fails, you could use `iptables` to switch the port on outgoing traffic to 25 (which is what I did at home.. bastard isp's, and their good intentions limiting spam ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, SMTP settings used by the [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function are defined in php.ini file ([smtp section](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp)). Either edit the file and make necessary changes or use [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the ini_set function

```
ini_set("smtp_port", "587");
```